# How do I keep changing my language settings on Windows XP by accident?

Tags: windows-xp, language, localization

I keep changing my language settings in Windows XP to English (US) or, even worse, Estonian by accident.  I've got the language bar on and I need to keep it.  I'm pretty sure I'm not accidentally clicking the bar.  Is there any other way I could be doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change Language layouts:

**Instructions for Windows XP**

1.Click Start and then Control Panel

2.In Control Panel, if you are in Category View, click on Switch to Classic View (top left corner)
3.Open Regional and Language Options.

4.Click on the Languages tab.

5.Under Text services and input languages, click on the Details button.

6.Under Installed services, click Add.

7.In the Add Input Language dialog box, choose the input language and keyboard layout or Input Method Editor (IME) you want to add.

8.Click OK twice. You should now see a language indicator in the System Tray (located at bottom right hand corner of the desktop by default). **You can switch between different input languages (= keyboard languages) by pressing the Alt + Shift keys**

If a language does not appear in the Input language list, the fonts for that language might not be installed. If that is the case, follow the instructions below

Comment: please consider to upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the current hotkey if it is interfeering with other shortcuts you use.

The shortcut key to switch languages by default is <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>

To change, simply open `Control Panel > Regional and Language Options` then under the `Languages Tab` click `Details`.

[image]

Next, click `Key Settings...` then you can change them there.

[image]